# HTML Tags in Javascript Alert() method

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to know if it's possible to add HTML tags to JavaScript `alert()` method, such as:

```
<b>
<ul>
<li>
```

etc.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why don't you just try it out: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) :)

Answer (score 52):

You can use all Unicode characters and the escape characters `\n` and `\t`. An example:

```js
document.getElementById("test").onclick = function() {
  alert(
    'This is an alert with basic formatting\n\n' 
    + "\t• list item 1\n" 
    + '\t• list item 2\n' 
    + '\t• list item 3\n\n' 
    + '▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬ஜ۩۞۩ஜ▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬\n\n' 
    + 'Simple table\n\n' 
    + 'Char\t| Result\n' 
    + '\\n\t| line break\n' 
    + '\\t\t| tab space'
  );
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Alert formatting</title>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<button id=test>Click</button>
```

Result in Firefox:

[image: screenshot Firefox]

You get the same look in almost all browsers.

Comment: Thnaks but is it possible to Bold or Underline some of the Text?

Comment: @SagarRawal There are some Unicode code points whose representation might look bold or underlined in some fonts. But that would exclude screen readers and users without matching fonts.

Comment: ஜ,  this character is 'ja'  sound in  a south Indian language malayalam.

Comment: @Rilwan "ja" means "yes" in German. :) But you are right, I don't recommend using sound characters for pure decoration.

Comment: Really a good solution! Thank you! It seems that chromium based browsers have a problem with "\t" tab space. It looks like a little flash symbol.

Answer (score 25):

alert() is a method of the window object that cannot interpret HTML tags

Comment: +1 ; To complete your answer: If you need a more advanced dialog, you can try JQueryUI Dialog http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 9):

You can add HTML into an alert string, but it will not render as HTML. It will just be displayed as a plain string. Simple answer: no.

Answer (score 7):

This is not possible.

Instead, you should create a fake window in Javascript, using something like [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Answer (score 4):

No, you can use only some escape sequences - **\n** for example (maybe only this one).

Answer (score 1):

`alert()`  doesn't support HTML, but you have some alternatives to format your message.

You can use Unicode characters as others stated, or you can make use of the [ES6 Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). For example:

```
...
.catch(function (error) {
  const alertMessage = `Error retrieving resource. Please make sure:
    • the resource server is accessible
    • you're logged in

    Error: ${error}`;
  window.alert(alertMessage);
}
```

Output:
[image]

As you can see, it maintains the line breaks and spaces that we included in the variable, with no extra characters.