# jQuery AJAX response parse as HTML and open in popup

Tags: jquery

I have used curl for cross browser scripting and i  get html  response

```
var url= 'http://'+$('#host').val() + "user/autolog";
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data:{username:$('#User_username').val()},
        url:url,
        dataType: "html",
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
            $('#User_autolog').val("1");
        },
});
```

i get html response ,,if i alert it it display text..
how can i convert it in to html..
so it would be something like a html form in popup ?

i get response

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html><head><title>Bandeau Agent - CCV</title><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript">function popup_agent(connect_url) {
            var option = 'width=500,height=150,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,menubar=no,location=no,toolbar=no,status=no';  
            var pname = 'popup_agent_';
            var winp = window.open(connect_url + '?@secid@=KXpF6GFT7XCh7F-ZmB2VlsYteT8L18qE-aJDKIXt0pCv2QSHdNFN-4ixfasv9_Rc', pname, option );
        }
</script></head><body><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">popup_agent('http://ccv-banner.viatelecom.com/bandeau.php');</script>
    <code>Votre popup agent doit s'afficher dans une nouvelle fenetre sur votre ecran. Si ce n'est pas le cas,<a href="#" onclick="popup_agent('http://ccv-banner.viatelecom.com/bandeau.php');">cliquez-ici</a>.</code>
</body></html>
```

Comment: what's the response data?

Comment: see response in question

Comment: I think what you need is [this](http://fancybox.net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise you have a look there to open a 'html form in popup':
[jquery ui modal form](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form)

On success, just trigger your form, and update it / your fields with the ajax answer.

It would be more helpful if you could give us an overview of your ajax answer :)

Comment: see responses edited in question..i dont want in modal ..just want to popup as response

Comment: OK so if you just want to display HTML in a 'normal' alert popup it is not possible, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278197/html-tags-in-javascript-alert-method)
You might have to consider jQuery UI...