# Italics Not Working In Javascript 'alert()' Method?

Tags: javascript, alert

I have been using jsFiddle to run Javascript, and am not currently using a library (i.e., jQuery). I would like to use italics in an alert box, but whenever I do it prints the

```
<em>Example</em>
```

tags. If I use

```
str.italics()
```

method it prints

```
<i>Example</i>
```

Why doesn't it work, and is there any way around this?

Comment: *"Why doesn't it work"* Because an `alert` doesn't render HTML. *"is there any way around this"* No.

Comment: possible duplicate of **[HTML Tags in Javascript Alert() method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278197/html-tags-in-javascript-alert-method)**

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll just forget it then.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Text BOLD in Alert or Confirm box?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620516/how-to-get-text-bold-in-alert-or-confirm-box)

Comment: If you want formatting text, use modal dialog box plugins like : http://www.wittysparks.com/2008/10/28/top-8-modal-dialogs-javascript/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't inject HTML in an alert. I would recommend avoiding using alerts for anything other than testing. Creating a custom alert dialog box / lightbox is not hard, and looks much nicer.