# How to show a table in jquery alert message

Tags: php, jquery

Now I'm creating a CRM by the help of PHP, MySql and JQuery. In this project I create a customer registration form. In this registration form, when user press the button, the form value is post to an another page without refreshing the page. I do this section by the help of JQuery ajex concept. 
After successfully insert the data into the database, the inserted data will be carry back into the jquery and here the data will be show as a popup and the alert message show the inserted data into a table format.

```
$.post(
                "customer.php",
                {
                    customer: "Insert",
                    f_name: "First_name",
                    m_name: "Middle_name",
                    l_name: "Last_name",
                    date: "Create_date",
                    phone: "Phone_number",
                    phone_alt: "Alternate_phone_no",
                    street_no: "street_no",
                    street_name: "Street_name",
                    zipcode: "zipcode",
                    city: "city",
                    state: "state",
                    country: "country",
                    email: "email",
                    email_alt: "Alternate_email"
                },
        function (data) {
            //alert(data);
            if (data == "<h1>Customer Data Successfully Inserted Into Database.</h1>")                    {                    
            } else {
                alert(data);
            }
        }
        );
```

> Blockquote

Now I have two question.
1> How to fetch more than one value from php to jquery?
And
2>How to show a table in alert message?

Comment: can you past your php file`s code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Jquery Script
--------------
<script>
  $(function() {
     $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
      modal: true,
  buttons: {
    Ok: function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
  }
});
});
</script>

HTML Alert Div
---------------
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <h1>Customer Data Successfully Inserted Into Database.</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for give a response. I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure about what you mean, but I think:

> 1: How to fetch more than one value from php to jQuery

Presumably, you're calling a PHP function to insert the data and return something. If you want to return several variables to jQuery, you can save everything you want in an array and return it. It will just show up in your "data" in your AJAX call.

So instead of doing something like:

```
return $username;
```

You should do something like

```
$dataArray = array('username' => 'John Doe', 'age' => 23);
return $dataArray;
```

That way, everything you've stored in the array will be returned to your jQuery.

2: How to show those value as a table format in alert message?

This is really a matter of just selecting the appropriate values from your returned data array and putting them in the mark-up you want. To see the structure of your data, put this in your AJAX call:

```
complete: function(data){
    console.log(data);   
}
```

And open your JavaScript console (just Google how to open your JavaScript console in the browser you're using). It will show you what the data is that was returned to your request.

edit: Just want to add: if you literally want a table mark-up in an alert() box, that's not possible. Better to just make a jQuery pop-up box with your own mark-up or something.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, alert() cannot interpret html code, but it DOES support escaped unicode characters so you can get a bit creative. This was answered here a while ago, maybe it'd help you get a little closer:

[HTML Tags in Javascript Alert() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278197/html-tags-in-javascript-alert-method)