# Using jQuery/JavaScript for modifying a HTML table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a HTML page which has one div and table. Then I have a PHP script which sould print the HTML for a table. Anyway, the table will not be modified. Does my `print` command include some kind of special charasters or is there something else which could be the reason?

I have a file index.html with the following jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function() {
    var kaavio = 106;

    jQuery.post("search.php", {
      kaavio: kaavio
    }).done(function(data) {
      $('#check').html(data);
    });
  }, 6000);
});
```

Here is the HTML of the file index.html:

```
<div id="check"></div>
<table id="paikka59"></table>
```

I also have a PHP file search.php and here is the code of it:

```
print "<script>document.getElementById('paikka59').innerHTML = '<tr><td class=\"pisteet\" style=\"border-top:2px solid #16B2B4;padding:0\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"painike painike-pisteet hae-muokattavaksi\" data-kilpailu=\"106\" data-kaavio=\"106\" data-kaaviokierros=\"11\" data-kaaviopaikka=\"59\" data-ab=\"A\" data-ottelu=\"181510\" data-muokattava=\"pisteet\"></a></td><td class=\"nimi\" style=\"border-top:2px solid #16B2B4;padding:0\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"painike painike-hae-muokattavaksi hae-muokattavaksi\" data-kilpailu=\"106\" data-kaavio=\"106\" data-kaaviokierros=\"11\" data-kaaviopaikka=\"59\" data-ab=\"A\" data-ottelu=\"181510\" data-muokattava=\"nimi\">2888 Salmi Risto</a></td><td class=\"tasoitus\" style=\"border-top:2px solid #16B2B4;padding:0\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"painike painike-hae-muokattavaksi\"></a></td></tr>        <tr><td class=\"pisteet\" style=\"padding:0\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"painike painike-pisteet hae-muokattavaksi\" data-kilpailu=\"106\" data-kaavio=\"106\" data-kaaviokierros=\"11\" data-kaaviopaikka=\"59\" data-ab=\"B\" data-ottelu=\"181510\" data-muokattava=\"pisteet\"></a></td><td class=\"nimi\" style=\"padding:0\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"painike painike-hae-muokattavaksi hae-muokattavaksi\" data-kilpailu=\"106\" data-kaavio=\"106\" data-kaaviokierros=\"11\" data-kaaviopaikka=\"59\" data-ab=\"B\" data-ottelu=\"181510\" data-muokattava=\"nimi\">2893 Rantanen Mikko</a></td><td class=\"tasoitus\" style=\"padding:0\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"painike painike-hae-muokattavaksi\"></a></td></tr>        <tr><td class=\"pelimuoto\"><!-- a --><a href=\"#\" class=\"painike painike-pelimuoto hae-muokattavaksi\" data-kilpailu=\"106\" data-kaavio=\"106\" data-kaaviokierros=\"11\" data-kaaviopaikka=\"59\" data-ab=\"\" data-ottelu=\"181510\" data-muokattava=\"voittopisteet\"></a></td><td class=\"ajankohta\"><!-- b --><a href=\"#\" class=\"painike hae-muokattavaksi\" data-kilpailu=\"106\" data-kaavio=\"106\" data-kaaviokierros=\"11\" data-kaaviopaikka=\"59\" data-ab=\"\" data-ottelu=\"181510\" data-muokattava=\"biljardipoyta\">Pöytä -</a><a href=\"#\" class=\"painike hae-muokattavaksi\" data-kaavio=\"106\" data-kaaviopaikka=\"59\" data-pelitapa=\"aika\">Ei aikataulutettu</a></td><td class=\"toiminnot\"><!-- c --><a href=\"#\" class=\"painike painike-toiminnot-play hae-muokattavaksi\" data-kilpailu=\"106\" data-kaavio=\"106\" data-kaaviokierros=\"11\" data-kaaviopaikka=\"59\" data-ab=\"\" data-ottelu=\"181510\" data-muokattava=\"ottelualoitus\"></a></td></tr>');</script>";
```

Comment: `print "<script>alert('<tr><td class="pisteet" style="border-top:2px solid #16B2B4;padding:0">` just this line should throw an error (any decent IDE would show you ^^) and syntax highlights here do (see the colors here `solid #16B2B4;`)

Comment: I have added `\"` now.

Comment: glad it helped :)

Comment: @OldPadawan I have updated my question, because I still have a problem.

Comment: thanks for UV, glad it solved it. Happy coding !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st, I didn't go further than the first mistake (in comments)

```
print "<script>alert('<tr><td class="pisteet" style="border-top:2px solid #16B2B4;padding:0">
```

-> just this line should throw an error

You **really** need to use a decent IDE :)

> your code shows :

```
print "<script>document.getElementById('paikka59').innerHTML = '<tr>
<td class=\"pisteet\" style=\"border-top:2px solid #16B2B4;padding:0\"><!-- a --></td></tr>');</script>";
```

> you should get rid of the extra `)` at the end

when testing, throws a warning/error

See [Element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) for different Syntax

EDIT: always check **all** of the stuff, especially looooong ones :)

Answer (score 0):

double quotes are creating a problem here.

Your print string is getting terminated at

```
print "<script>alert('<tr><td class="     // rest all code will be skipped
```

Use \" in such situation. Your print statemnet will become like

```
print "<script>alert('<tr><td class=\"pisteet\" ...  </tr>');</script>";
```

One more thing, you can not add html tags inside alert(). You can only insert plaintext to alert(), confirm() and prompt() boxes.

Have a look at below thread :
[HTML Tags in Javascript Alert() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278197/html-tags-in-javascript-alert-method)

Comment: Thanks, I solved that. No problem with that anymore.

Comment: I still have a problem. Please take a look at my updated question.

Comment: you can not add html tags inside alert(). You can only insert plaintext to alert(), confirm() and prompt() boxes.

Comment: Yes, as you can see I have modified my code and I am using a table instead of alert().

Comment: So, is innerHTML not working? check sourcecode of your HTML page. can you see this code in source?