# How, Right Click a <tr>, run php to retrieve data, display result in an alert?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I've read and tried many solutions, none are working. Here is my latest. As you can see all I'm trying to do is display an alert box on screen with the data retrieved from the MySQL using PHP.

My HTML looks like this:

```
...
<td $brbCols class=\"editCS1\" oncontextmenu=\"getLastLogin('$row[callsign]');return false;\"                   id=\"callsign:$row[recordID]\" style=\'text-transform:uppercase\'>                                                               $row[callsign]   </td>
...
```

Right clicking on the above code runs this,
The getLastLogin javascript looks like this:

```
function getLastLogin() {
    $('tr').on('contextmenu', 'td', function(e) { //Get td under tr and invoke on contextmenu
        e.preventDefault(); //Prevent defaults'
            var idparm = $(this).attr('id');
            var arparm = idparm.split(":");
            var id     = arparm[1];
            id = id.replace(/\s+/g, '');
            var call   = $(this).html();
            call = call.replace(/\s+/g, '');

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "getLastLogIn.php",
            data: {call : call, id : id},
            success: function(response) {
                alert(response);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Not OKay');
            }
        });
    });

}
```

The PHP:

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors',1); 
    error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

    require_once "creddtls.php";

    $call = $_POST['call'];
    $id   = $_POST['id'];

$sql2 = "SELECT recordID, id, Fname, Lname,  grid, creds, 
                 email, latitude, longitude, tactical, callsign, logdate, netID, activity
        FROM NetLog 
        WHERE callsign = '$call'
        ORDER BY netID DESC 
        LIMIT 1,1 " ; 

    $stmt2 = $db_found->prepare($sql2);
    $stmt2->execute();

    $result = $stmt2->fetch();
        $recordID   = $result[0];   $email      = $result[6];
        $id         = $result[1];   $latitude   = $result[7];
        $Fname      = $result[2];   $longitude  = $result[8];
        $Lname      = $result[3];   $creds      = $result[5];   
        $tactical   = $result[9];   $grid       = $result[4];
        $callsign   = $result[10];  $netID      = $result[12];
        $logdate    = $result[11];  $activity   = $result[13];

        $msg = "<b>Last Check-in::</b>
            <br>$callsign, $Fname $Lname
            <br><b>eMail::</b>$email
            <br><b>Was on::</b> $logdate
            <br><b>Net ID::</b>  $netID, $activity
            <br><br>
            $recordID
            ";
        echo "$msg";
?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because `$_GET` data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Comment: It's traditional to use the HTTP `POST` method to send in form data.

Comment: @tadman No form is being submitted. And based on the logic in the PHP script it is a data retrieval so (without further context) I'd say that GET is appropriate in this situation.

Comment: @Aknosis This looks like some kind of search operation being performed which is why I think POST is a better fit. You *could* use `DELETE` to do it, nobody's going to stop you, but it'd be confusing.

Comment: I've changed it to GET which is what I meant in the first place since I'm only getting info not submitting any. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278197/html-tags-in-javascript-alert-method The message in PHP is returning HTML but the javascript alert box doesn't interpret HTML.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Tags in Javascript Alert() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278197/html-tags-in-javascript-alert-method)

Comment: @BSMP Not a duplicate, did you read the content in this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong or not the code writes to the lli DIV. So I added $("#lli").modal(); to the Javascript to open it in a modal dialog.

All is now well.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the data passed via ajax with the wrong superglobal.

You are looking at POST data, but your ajax call is using GET

Change `$_POST` to `$_GET`

Comment: This is only part of the problem. The javascript calls there make no sense.

Comment: @Dekel While I appreciate knowing I'm doing it wrong it would be even better if I knew how to do it right. I need more than chastisement, I need help and an example or fix my code and tell me why.